# "Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit" at R startup

Tags: r, c

I am getting the following error at R startup and couldn't find a solution yet (C stack usage is too close to the limit). Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) -- "Lost Library Book"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error: C stack usage  7969792 is too close to the limit
>
```

Comment: You might try to delete the `.Rdata` file.

Comment: thanks, I did it but I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I commented all lines in my .Rprofile (all blogdown related) and it fixed the issue.